# How to implement a ScalaTest FunSuite to avoid boilerplate Spark code and import implicits

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest

I try to refactor a ScalaTest FunSuite test to avoid boilerplate code to init and destroy Spark session.

The problem is that I need import implicit functions but using before/after approach only variables (var fields) can be use, and to import it is necessary a value (val fields).

**The idea is to have a new clean Spark Session every test execution.**

I try to do something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SparkSession}
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfter, FunSuite}

object SimpleWithBeforeTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter {

  var spark: SparkSession = _
  var sc: SparkContext = _
  implicit var sqlContext: SQLContext = _

  before {
    spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .appName("Spark session for testing")
      .getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
  }

  after {
    spark.sparkContext.stop()
  }

  test("Import implicits inside the test 1") {
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    // Here other stuff
  }

  test("Import implicits inside the test 2") {
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    // Here other stuff
  }
```

But in the line `import sqlContext.implicits._` I have an error

> Cannot resolve symbol sqlContext

How to resolve this problem or how to implements the tests class?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base), which pretty much handles all the boilerplate code.

Here is [a blog post](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/09/making-apache-spark-testing-easy-with-spark-testing-base/) by the creator, explaining how to use it.

And here is a simple example from their [wiki](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/wiki/DatasetSuiteBase):

```
class test extends FunSuite with DatasetSuiteBase {
  test("simple test") {
    val sqlCtx = sqlContext
    import sqlCtx.implicits._

    val input1 = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3)).toDS
    assertDatasetEquals(input1, input1) // equal

    val input2 = sc.parallelize(List(4, 5, 6)).toDS
    intercept[org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException] {
        assertDatasetEquals(input1, input2) // not equal
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a new immutable variable  for the spark context and assign the var to it before importing implicits.

```
class MyCassTest extends FlatSpec with BeforeAndAfter {

  var spark: SparkSession = _

  before {
    val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()    
    spark = SparkSession.
      builder().
      config(sparkConf).
      master("local[*]").
      getOrCreate()
  }

  after {
    spark.stop()
  }

  "myFunction()" should "return 1.0 blab bla bla" in {
    val sc = spark
    import sc.implicits._

    // assert ...
  }
}
```

Comment: you're not supposed to manage the life-cycle of the sparkSession during tests.
Please use the SharedSparkContext (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/SharedSparkContext.scala).

Comment: Can u let me know the maven dependencies for the "SharedSparkSession"